# Can't save data from frontend in database, problem is that I can't enter the POST function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I use Node.js, React.js, phpMyadmin(mysql), express and axios.
I cant save data into database. I get these errors:

```
POST http://localhost:3400/Registration 404 (Not Found) 

Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',...
```

but I figure out that I can't get in app.post() function.

Here is code:

```
const express = require('express')//simple express server
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors=require('cors')

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    password: '',
    database: 'gdje_si_veceras?'
});
app.post("/Registration", (req, res) => {
    console.log("hej");
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    db.query("INSERT INTO users(firstName,lastName,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", [firstName, lastName, email, password],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                res.send("Values Inserted")
            }
        }
    );
});
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("jej your serveer is running!");
});
```

The output in console is:

```
jej your serveer is running!
```

but it should be:

```
hej
jej your serveer is running!
```

Comment: Why did you make the `POST` request to `localhost:3400`? Your express app is running on `3001`, I think.

Comment: Because localhost:3400... is where frontend page is, from where I use data.

Comment: 404 error means that URL was not found.

Comment: Please try to make a request to `localhost:3001`.